# Can't get any db data out of Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I completed the Meteor 'simple todo' tutorial and thought I'd gotten the basic gist of how it works. However I'm starting my own project now and am hitting problems immediately.

Whatever I try I cannot get any data out of Meteor and into my template, or even into a `console.log`. It's always `undefined`. I've even double-checked the collections via `meteor mongo` in the terminal and the data I'm passing in is correct. I've even tried hardcoding the document id.

I'm hoping that someone can point at what must be obviously wrong with my code.

This is the current iteration that doesn't work, but I seem to have tried every variation I can find on the net:

JS:

```
Pros = new Mongo.Collection("pros");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("pros");
  Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main'
  });
  Router.route('/brief/:_id', function () {
    this.render('Brief', {
      data: function(){
            var proid = this.params._id;
            return Pros.findOne({ _id: proid });
        }
    });
  });
}
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("pros", function () {
    return Pros.find();
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="main">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="brief">
  <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
</template>
```

(I've also tried the above in a foreach on `pros`)

DB data (via a find command in the terminal)

```
db.pros.find({});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55915761145c29018ac97edb"), "name" : "Jimbob" }
```

I've now also tried the following which hasn't yielded any different results (It just stays on loading state):

```
Pros = new Mongo.Collection("pros");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main'
  });
  Router.route('/brief/:_id', {
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('pros', this.params._id);
    },
    action: function () {
      this.render('brief');
    }
  });
}
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish('pros', function(proId) {
    return Pros.findOne(proId);
  });
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please also show your template and/or the code you used to print to the console.

Comment: also, which router are you using? iron-router?

Comment: Yup, iron router - I'll paste in some template code now but I don't think it'll add much to the discussion :)

Comment: Added in the template code, I also pasted in another solution I've tried with no better results (directly from the iron router docs).

Comment: check your subscription status with mongol https://atmospherejs.com/msavin/mongol

Comment: In the browser console what do you get if you type `Pros.find().fetch()` and press enter?

Comment: @MichaelMason Nada `[]`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @JuanCrg90 - useful! The Pros collections is showing as blank - but that's verifiably not true, so I guess Meteor isn't grabbing the collection properly?

Answer (score 2):

You're using ObjectIDs in Meteor which isn't the default (Meteor generates 17 character strings instead of Mongo ObjectIDs when inserting documents)

Try something like:

```
data: function () {
    Pros.findOne({ _id: new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id)});
}
```

Comment: aha! I inserted the document via the command line (albeit using `meteor mongo`) so I guess that's what caused that hiccup. Is it not really possible to insert via other means then if you need to reference by ID? Seems like a slightly odd limitation?

Comment: And woop - that did it!

Comment: You can still insert from command line but you'd need to set an _id to prevent Mongo from generating it's own. Calling `Random.id()` in the browser console does the trick but it's all still a bit manual.

Comment: I created a gist a while ago of the random code from meteor for this reason. It's coffeescript and server side only but could be useful to you... https://gist.github.com/mjmasn/e8bd17d89a02d085c06b

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `findOne` in publish. It returns just one object, instead of a cursor. Also, add the `data` field back into your client route. Try this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main'
  });
  Router.route('/brief/:_id', {
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('pros', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function(){
      var proid = this.params._id;
      return Pros.findOne({ _id: proid });
    },
    action: function () {
      this.render('brief');
    }
  });
}

if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish('pros', function(proId) {
        return Pros.find({_id: proId});
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok this has pushed me past the loading state, however `{{ name }}` is still outputting blank - I'll investigate a little further.

Comment: Replacing `return Pros.find({_id: proId});` in the `publish` statement with `return Pros.find({});` is at least bringing the whole collection into the template (verified using `msavin:mongol`) - so there's something wrong with the findOne statement? But the ID I'm using is definitely the only ID in the collection :/

Comment: Although I've just noticed that the document ID is flagged as `_str` type, shouldn't be an ObjectId?